# How to detect and split sections of an image

Tags: image-processing, image

I'm new to Mathematica and I was trying to split the following image into horizontal sections, just above every square box. I have done some pre-processing but I can't figure out how to "locate" the boxes and split them at their topmost boundaries, until the next box's topmost boundary.

**EDIT - 2**
( Better info about previous edits can be gleamed from the accepted answer )

[image]

This image has the proper text segment I wish to extract, I just need to create a corpus with the sentences with the corresponding boxes, which I'm choosing as a guide for comp. vision.

[image]

I need to chunk it to components segments

1. The sentence lengths and thus their spacing on a page is variable.
2. There are variable number of such sentence groups in a page. ( As    shown in **Full Page** )

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update 2:

We'll work this case by first finding the most common left-most pixel. Note that this won't work for the previous update, as that vertical separator will be it. However it should be possible to detect and strip that vertical separator.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/APXIy.png"];

norgba = ColorCombine@Take[ColorSeparate@img, UpTo[3]];
binarized = Binarize@norgba;
data = ImageData@binarized;

leftmosts =
  FirstPosition[#, 0, Nothing] & /@ data // Counts // ReverseSort // 
   KeyMap[First];

blockstart = First@Keys@leftmosts;
```

Then we find the maximum contiguous block of black pixels (in our binarized image) starting from there.

```
contiguous =
  Split[
   Position[#, 0, {1}] & /@ data // Flatten // Sort // 
    DeleteDuplicates,
   Abs[# - #2] == 1 &
   ];

pixelBlock = SelectFirst[contiguous, MemberQ[blockstart]];
```

Then we'll apply the same row splitting algorithm, but this time allowing much longer stretches of white pixels (so that the wrapped lines are captured). Then we'll find the same set of rows defined by these blocks, then select out those that don't have a marker:

```
splits =
  Block[{block = False, counts = 0, countmax = 50}, 
   SplitBy[data, (If[Length@Counts[#] > 1, block = True;
       counts = 0;, counts++;
       block = (block && counts <= countmax)];
      block) &]];

rowsRaw = 
  Partition[Riffle[Most@#, Rest@#] &@Accumulate[Length /@ splits], 2];

rows =
  Select[
   rowsRaw,
   MemberQ[
     Take[data, #][[All, pixelBlock]] // Flatten,
     0
     ] &
   ];
```

Finally we take from the maximum right position of a marker and crop out whitespace:

```
fullcolordata = ImageData@img;

chunks =
  ImageCrop@Image@
      Take[fullcolordata, #][[All, Last@pixelBlock + 1 ;; -1]] & /@ 
   rows;

chunks
```

[image: chunks 3]

#### Update

This is for the updated version of the question.

First we need to get an appropriate image to work on. First we'll binarize and then take only the chunk to the left of the vertical divider and below the horizontal one:

```
img = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8eZx.png";

norgba = ColorCombine@Most@ColorSeparate@img;

binarized = Binarize@norgba;
data = ImageData@binarized;
flipped = Transpose@data;
rowseparator =
  Max@
   Position[
    data,
    Alternatives @@ MinimalBy[data, Total],
    {1}
    ];
rowdropped = 
 Take[data, {
  rowseparator + 5 (* a fudge factor could be much bigger, too*), 
  -1}];
columnseparator =
  Min@
   Position[
    flipped,
    Alternatives @@ MinimalBy[flipped, Total],
    {1}
    ];

chopped =
  Transpose@Take[Transpose@rowdropped, columnseparator - 1];

Take[chopped, 1000] // Image
```

[image: chopped]

Then we split as before:

```
splits =
  Block[{block = False, counts = 0, countmax = 3},
   SplitBy[chopped,
    (If[Length@Counts[#] > 1, block = True;
       counts = 0;, counts++;
       block = (block && counts <= countmax)];
      block) &]];
```

Then we need the row spans each of the chunks is in (`rows`) and the vertical range that the indicator is in (`subblocks`):

```
rows =
  Partition[
   Riffle[Most@#,
      Rest@#] &@
    Accumulate[
     Length /@ splits
     ],
   2
   ];

subblocks =
  If[Length@# > 0,
       {0, 10} + Through[{Min, Max}[Keys@#]],
       None] &@
     (Function[Through[{Min, Max}[#]]] /@

       GroupBy[First -> Last]@Position[#, 0]
      ) & /@ splits;
```

Then we thread over these together, first taking the row range, then taking the subrange:

```
fullcolordata = ImageData@img;

chunks =
  MapThread[
   Take[
     Take[fullcolordata, rowseparator + #],
     #2
     ] &, {
    rows,
    DeleteCases[subblocks, None]
    }];
```

And then we view:

```
ImageCrop@Image[#, ColorSpace -> "RGB"] & /@ chunks
```

[image: fullcolor chunks]

And if you just want the line text you can use this:

```
fullcolorrowchopped =
  Transpose@
   Take[
    Transpose@Take[fullcolordata, {rowseparator + 5, -1}],
    {columnseparator + 5, -1}
    ];

fchopped =
  Select[
   MapThread[
    Take[
      Take[fullcolorrowchopped, #],
      #2
      ] &, {
     rows,
     DeleteCases[subblocks, None]
     }],
   Length@Counts[#] > 1 &
   ];

ImageCrop@Image[#, ColorSpace -> "RGB"] & /@ fchopped
```

[image: just text]

#### Original

So we can do this by looking at the pixel values and just splitting where we see whitespace.

First get the image and its pixel rows:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPX7R.png"];
data = ImageData@img;
```

Then we'll use a procedural style loop to chunk our data by the following criterion:

Either
 1. There's more than a single color pixel in it

Or
 1. Up to n rows previous there was more than a single pixel color

Here's my loop. It's not optimized and a pretty lazy, off the top of my head way to do it, but hopefully it's good enough:

```
splits =
  Block[{
    block = False,
    counts = 0,
    countmax = 3
    },
   SplitBy[data,
    (
      If[Length@Counts[#] > 1,
       block = True;
       counts = 0;,
       counts++;
       block = (block && counts <= countmax)
       ];
      block
      ) &
    ]
   ];
```

Then we'll crop whitespace and format images:

```
chunks = ImageCrop@*Image /@ splits;
```

And then delete those images that are just whitespace:

```
imgs =
  Select[chunks,
   Length@Counts[Flatten[ImageData[#], 1]] > 1 &
   ];
```

And let's see how we did:

```
imgs[[;; 10]]
```

[image: image chunks]

There's probably a cleaner way to do this, but this was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: This is a great solution to the problem - I'll accept it:)

But sadly, I mis-framed my question as I realize now. The thing is I need to split the images in the **page** image above. If possible, could you help me find a solution to the updated question above.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma No need to accept so soon. Someone might come along with something better. You mean just split at the 175, 176, etc? I'll give that a bit of thought. It's a harder thing to do -- although presumably one of the many machine learning experts on this site will have something.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma will all of your pages look like that? (i.e. the number bar will be thin and everything else will be thick?) If so I can do this in a way similar to what I did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141281/38205)

Comment: Nope, actually the only thing common to the corpus is that there are big boxes, signifying the script name next to the text. The number line etc are not there in most other texts.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma OHHH. (Just saw your update) This one I can do. Give me a moment.

Comment: Sure, you're being truly helpful  :)

Comment: @AbhinavSharma as long as the sentences don't wrap lines this should work. I just took everything to the right of the little indicator bubble.

Comment: Thanks man! But, it seems that the snippet for `norgba` is missing in the very first block :)

Comment: @AbhinavSharma Right you are. I just put it back in.

Comment: You're awesome with Mathematica!!
Unfortunately we do have wrapped lines, I'll update the question for another image from the corpus.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma Can I depend on some form of fixed indicator for a line on the left hand side? Like a box or blob? If I can then this should be doable in a general(ish) case by finding the alignment point of the blobs, chunking by whitespace, then taking from the indicator position on. If not I'll need to think a bit more.

Comment: Yes, of course. This seems like a good idea since the offset of the squares from the left side from the image is almost always the same on every page. So, if we could base the entire  chucking function on  [ 1 ]  The margin of boxes from the left edge of the image [ 2 ] Taking the pixel position of the "roof" of each square as the region of previous box.  [3] There are varying number of sentences in each page, the numbering before the squares  indicates a sentence cluster.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma that doesn't matter too much. Just that I can know that after I make my chunks I can search for a box. I have to go for now, but I'll get back to this.

Comment: Hey, I was thinking this over. You know, we can easily add lines on the left margin using mathematica to re-use a lot of this code.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma sorry to take so long to get back to this. Been kinda busy. I think, by replacing that vertical separator in the last case, that the update I just made should be applicable to the previous update, too.

Comment: no issues - you've been immensely helpful :) Though, I think that the snippet for `blockstart` is missing.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma How embarrassing. Second time that's happened I think. It's up now.

Comment: Well, that makes no difference at all :) Again, thanks a ton man!!

Comment: @AbhinavSharma glad to help. Hopefully it was informative as a way to do these types of image manipulations and showed some of the kinds of tricks and patterns you can look for.

Comment: Absolutely, the first time I've seen a power user of Mathematica! I learnt a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the sentences, you could use TextRecognize if the text is what you really want.

In:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8eZx.png"] // Rasterize;
ts = Block[{$Language = #}, 
     TextRecognize[img]] & /@ {"ChineseTraditional", "Chinese"};
ts // Map[StringSplit[#, "\n"] &] // Map[MatrixForm]
Transpose[{ts, {{5, 12}, {8, 15}}}] // 
 Map[StringSplit[First@#, "\n"][[Last@#]] &]
```

Out:

[image]

```
{{"他在廚房 。 他在煮束西 口", 
  "你踩 到 我的 腳 了 。\[LongDash] 對不起"}, 
{"他在厨房 \[Degree] 他正在做饭 。", 
  "你踩着我脚了 口 一对不起 口"}}
```

Comment: Hey, actually the trouble is I don't have that kind of a bandwidth to send this across. And conversion to smaller image chunks is necessary since we have a pipeline to process them via tesseract - on the campus.

Comment: All right, I just give another way of thinking. If it's done in the cloud, the bandwidth problem could be alleviated.

Comment: I agree, thanks for this one though :)