# How to get the check result

Tags: image-processing

Suppose I have a image `mark`

```
mark=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0A6a.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And image `empty`

```
empty=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYqMl.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you see,they are aligned well

```
HighlightImage[mark, ColorNegate[Binarize[mark]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### I want to get a result like

> `{{d,b,c,b,c},{c,d},{c,b,d}}`

And a list `{{1,2,3,4,5},{8,9},{15,16,17}}`

---

This is current try

```
bin = ColorNegate[Binarize[empty]] // FillingTransform;
rects = Values[
   ComponentMeasurements[Dilation[bin, 1] // FillingTransform, 
    "BoundingBox"]];
module = Binarize[
  Show[bin, 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], FaceForm[White], Rectangle @@@ rects}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
markBin = 
  DeleteSmallComponents[
   ImageSubtract @@ (Binarize[ColorNegate[#]] & /@ {mark, empty})];
rects = Values[
   ComponentMeasurements[Dilation[markBin, 1] // FillingTransform, 
    "BoundingBox"]];
markResult = 
 Binarize[Show[markBin, 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], FaceForm[White], Rectangle @@@ rects}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mark the result

```
HighlightImage[module,Values[ComponentMeasurements[markResult, "Centroid"]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

1. But I don't know how to get that *expectation list*.
2. When the `empy` and `mark` is following layout,I have no solution to judge its orientation.

empty

[image]

mark

[image]

Answer (score 4):

So here's an adaption to [this answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147500/38205) where I did some of this splitting work.

First we'll define some stuff to split pixel columns:

```
splitPixelBlocks[data_, blockSize : _?IntegerQ : 50] :=

  Block[{block = False, counts = 0, countmax = blockSize},
   SplitBy[data,
    (If[Length@Counts[#] > 1, block = True;
       counts = 0;, counts++;
       block = (block && counts <= countmax)];
      block) &]
   ];
deleteConstantBlocks[data_] :=
  DeleteCases[data, {{(pixel_) ..} ..}];
splitColumnBlocks[img_?ImageQ, blockSize : _?IntegerQ : 50] :=

  deleteConstantBlocks@
    splitPixelBlocks[Transpose@ImageData[img], blockSize] // 
   Map[Image@*Transpose@*ImageData@*ImageCrop@*Image];
prepImg[img_?ImageQ] :=
  ImageClip[img, {0, .9}, {0, 1}];
```

Then we split those:

```
cols = splitColumnBlocks[
  img = prepImg@
    Uncompress[
     FromCharacterCode[
      Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0A6a.png"], 
        "Byte"]]]]
  ]
```

[image: columns]

Then split the rows in the columns:

```
splitRowBlocks[img_?ImageQ, blockSize : _?IntegerQ : 5] :=

 Image /@ deleteConstantBlocks@
   splitPixelBlocks[ImageData[img], blockSize]

rows = splitRowBlocks /@ cols
```

[image: rows]

Then finally split the columns of each of those:

```
rowData = Map[splitColumnBlocks[#, 10] &] /@ rows
```

[image: row splits]

That's our data prep. Now theoretically we could just use `TextRecognize` but...

```
TextRecognize[ImagePad[First[#], 25, White]] & /@ Flatten @ rowData

{"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "15", "16", "17"}
```

So we'll have to be a bit smarter about it:

```
tableHeaders =
 Map[
   Replace[
       TextRecognize[#,
        RecognitionPrior -> "SparseText"
        ],
       "" :>
        TextRecognize[#,
         RecognitionPrior -> "Character"
         ]
       ] &[
     ImageClip[ImagePad[First[#], 25, White], {.95, 1}, {0, 1}]
     ] &
   ] /@ rowData

{{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, {"8", "9"}, {"15", "16", "17"}}
```

It's slow, but it gets the job done.

Now we find the answers:

```
getAns[row_, thresh_: .8] :=
 {"A", "B", "C", "D"}[[
   SelectFirst[Range[4],
    Mean@Flatten@ImageData[row[[#]]] < thresh &
    ]
   ]]

Map[getAns@*Rest] /@ rowData

{{"D", "B", "C", "B", "C"}, {"C", "D"}, {"C", "B", "D"}}
```

And I think that's what you wanted, right?

The second layout is slightly harder, but we can do it in a similar way.

Comment: Amazing..It very cool